# Potential issue that plugin could have when it will be installed on several sites

Tags: plugins, plugin-development

I am pretty new to WordPress plugin development. I am developing a plugin and one of my colleagues said that i should to pay attention to the case when this plugin will be installed on a few sites. I can't figure out what he was talking about and what could be the problem. Can you tell me what places in the code should I pay attention to, maybe someone has already encountered such a problem?

Comment: That's a vague comment from your colleague and a difficult one to answer without seeing the code you both are referring to. You might get the best answer from your colleague by just asking them. Maybe read through the Handbook on [Best Practices](https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/plugin-basics/best-practices/) and general [Development Guidelines](https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/intro/)

Comment: I don't know what your colleague is referring to, not without knowing what the plugin is meant to do and how it's intended to work. I'd ask your colleague what they meant and for an example of what could go wrong. There's also the chance your colleague was mistaken. But to help you further we need to know more